# How can I change my backend from the current webpack dev server to express?

Tags: express, reactjs, webpack, backend, webpack-dev-server

I've been going through a tutorial describing Reactjs webpack and webpac dev server. But now I have to use express in my real project. How can I change the server, or can I just add a new server using express, in this case how can I manage two localhost? you can see my webpack.config.js below.

```js
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./app/main.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        //test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "index.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

Now I have built a server by express as well, which listens to 3000:

```js
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Server started: http://localhost:' + app.get('port') + '/');
});
```

my webpack dev server has the path ./node_modules/.bin and it listens to 8080. The question is what should I add in the express file to take over webpack dev server. Or If you think I can combine them, How should I operate on express in this case? Thanks!

Comment: You can start your express server as usual using `node server.js` and have the client connect to port 3000 and direct all api calls to the express server.

Comment: So I don't need to care about webpack dev server anymore right? This webpack dev server is for auto recompiling the server if there is any change happened. maybe I could do the same with nodemon for express right?? sorry for my newbie question :)

Comment: pls look at docs of webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware. you need those. you can find the examples from redux's [examples](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples)

Comment: hello kevin! are you good at express with react? I got some questions :)

Answer (score 0):

you can combine express with webpack-dev-middleware

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var config = require('./webpack.config.dev');

var app = express();
var compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:3000');
});
```

Comment: thanks man! But I'm wondering if I can do the auto server recompiling with express, why should I use webpack dev server?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you right. Do you want a feature like hot reloading? You can take a look at [this project](https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-boilerplate) it is using express with dev-middleware for bundling and hot-middleware for hot reloading.

Comment: But I can use nodemon instead of hot reloading right? they are working in similar way?

Comment: For a react project I would recommend hot loading because it is only reloading the javascript modules that change and not the whole application. [React Hot Loader 3.0](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader), [demo](https://vimeo.com/100010922)

Comment: you got the point! one more thing: the code you showed me has ( var config = require('./webpack.config.dev'); ).  Is the webpack.config.dev file same as my webpack.config.js ?

Comment: yes you can use the webpack config file that you have posted in your question. In my project the config for development is called webpack.config.dev.js and the production config is webpack.config.prod.js

Comment: Hello steffen, help me for one more thing. I use histiry=hashhistory for my routes now, so I can get to any page by using #, for example localhost:8080/#/login. But when I change to history=createBrowserHistory(), I only can come in login page through my home by clicking on login button. But it shows "can not get/login" when I type localhost:8080/login in url. I'm going to create a express server and database to handle login. Should I change my history variable at all? why? and what methods should I use in server to get login request and push back another route to the frontend?  1000 thanks :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with history.js but you can look [here](http://andrewhfarmer.com/starter-project/) for a starter kit project to get some sample code for history based routing. There are a lot of projects demonstrating react-router

Comment: Thanks! This is great! how can you guys find such sources? haha